# How to add attributes to an existing xml string stored as a field from the rest of the columns in the same row using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My question is tough to explain so let me give you a visual. First, I have this view to work with:
[image: SQL View]

I have the XML in the `AuditValue` column. I want to add every other column to the XML column as attributes. So my first row would look like this:

```
<row ManufacturerID="6" 
     ManufacturerName="AMES999" 
     IsDeleted="0" Concurrency="AAAAAAABTAk=" 
     EntryID="1" 
     TableName="Manufacturers" 
     AuditDate="2013-01-30 15:48:24.69" ChangeType="U"/>
```

I would like to do this dynamically. Semantically, I mean: For every column in the view except for the AuditValue column, add the column to the AuditValue column XML as an attribute.

I am SQL stupid for the most part. I know the basics, but that is about it. Help would be most appreciated. Any more info I can or need to provide, please let me know. I'm happy to provide anything needed.

Comment: OK, I'm not getting any feedback yet so I am thinking that my question is a little two general. So, if someone could explain how I could insert an attribute into the xml (the AuditValue column) from one of the other columns and I think I can figure out the rest. I would, of course, post my complete solution once I obtained it. Thanks

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? If the current attributes in the XML is known you can query the attributes along with the columns and rebuild the XML from scratch. Otherwise you have to add one attribute at a time in a while loop over the columns you want to add to the XML using `xmlcolumn.modify('insert ...)`.

Comment: Hi Mikael. Thanks for responding. This is SQL Server. And no, there is no way to know the existing attributes. Each existing XML element may have unique or different attributes with respect to the rest of the elements. The while loop may be the easiest route. I will do some reading. At least that gets me a start. Any other ideas or guidance are certainly welcome.

Comment: OK, I realize how ridiculous this is going to sound, but I don't want to permanently modify the xml in the table. If I do a xmlcolumn.modify... will it actually change the fields in the table or for just the view?

Comment: So you want to query your table and have the XML column merged with the other columns as attributes in the result set?

Comment: That is exactly what I want Mikael. So my result set would only consist of the one XML column with all of the other fields added as attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found no way to add the attributes to existing nodes in a query. You could of course create a temporary table from your table and modify the XML in the temporary table adding one attribute at a time.

Another option would be to accept the fact that this is hard and decide that you want to build  an XML that has all the data but not in the exact way you want. For example this query.

```sql
select *
from YourTable
for xml raw
```

Will give you XML like this.

```xml
<row EntryID="1" TableName="Manufacturers" AuditDate="2013-01-30T15:48:24.690" ChangeType="U">
  <AuditValue>
    <row ManufacturerID="6" ManufacturerName="AMES999" IsDeleted="0" Concurrency="AAAAAAABTAk=" />
  </AuditValue>
</row>
```

Or you could use this

```sql
select EntryID as '@EntryID',
       TableName as '@TableName',
       AuditDate as '@AuditDate',
       ChangeType as '@ChangeType',
       AuditValue as '*'
from YourTable
for xml path('row')
```

to get the XML

```xml
<row EntryID="1" TableName="Manufacturers" AuditDate="2013-01-30T15:48:24.690" ChangeType="U">
  <row ManufacturerID="6" ManufacturerName="AMES999" IsDeleted="0" Concurrency="AAAAAAABTAk=" />
</row>
```

If you are ready to get really ugly with this you can try a combination of XML and string manipulation.

```sql
select cast(replace(cast(AuditValue as nvarchar(max)), '/>', '') +
       stuff(cast((
                  select EntryID, TableName, AuditDate, ChangeType
                  for xml raw, type
                  ) as nvarchar(max)) ,1 , 4, '') as xml) as AuditValue
from YourTable
```

Result:

```xml
<row ManufacturerID="6" 
     ManufacturerName="AMES999" 
     IsDeleted="0" 
     Concurrency="AAAAAAABTAk=" 
     EntryID="1" 
     TableName="Manufacturers" 
     AuditDate="2013-01-30T15:48:24.690" 
     ChangeType="U" />
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0cfcd/2)

Comment: Holy Bee-Jeezers Batman! That was thorough and helpful Mikael. I can't thank you enough. I've tried your code and it definitely seems to work. I tip my hat and thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: I didn't end up finding anything built in that would accomplish what I wanted. Mikael's post shows how to get the job done and is quite helpful.